# Does the Angular CLI minify/uglify assets?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently upgraded to angular 8 and I've noticed a few issues with javascript in the assets folder being uglified.

Is this some sort of new thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minifying JavaScript in the `assets` folder was reported as `angular-cli` bug. See issue [**ng build --prod --aot minifies js files from assets folder**](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15423).

This has been fixed as of August 26, 2019. Try upgrading to the latest version of the Angular CLI.

Comment: Thanks.  Upgrading the angular cli didn't work, but it looks like maybe I need to specifically upgrade @angular-devkit/build-angular